# how to select value from dropdown with formcontrolname in protractor?

Tags: protractor

```html
<select _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="Designation" required=""><option _ngcontent-c1="" value="">Select Designation</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c1="" value="CEO">CEO</option><option _ngcontent-c1="" value="GM">GM</option><option _ngcontent-c1="" value="BodyGuard">BodyGuard</option><option _ngcontent-c1="" value="Executive">Executive</option></select>
```

For above html i am trying to select value from dropdown using protractor.
Tried following but not working.

```
var EmpDesignation = element(by.cssContainingText('body.modal-open:nth-child(2) modal-container.modal.fade.show:nth-child(7) div.modal-dialog div.modal-content form.form-horizontal.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched div.modal-body div.form-row:nth-child(2) div.col-md-10 > select.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched:nth-child(3)', 'CEO'));
EmpDesignation.click();
```

> Error: Failed: No element found using locator:
>   by.cssContainingText("body.modal-open:nth-child(2)
>   modal-container.modal.fade.show:nth-child(7) div.modal-dialog
>   div.modal-content
>   form.form-horizontal.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched div.modal-body
>   div.form-row:nth-child(2) div.col-md-10 >
>   select.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched:nth-child(3)",
>   "CEO")

There are multiple class with class name 'form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid'.

Can anyone suggest way out of this? can we use formcontrolname tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it like this

```
let EmpDesignation = element(by.xpath('//select[@formcontrol="Designation"]'));

EmpDesignation.sendKeys('CEO'); //Option 1
EmpDesignation.element(by.cssContainingText('option','CEO')) //Option 2
```

This does assume that `formcontrol="Designation"` is unique however. If that assumption is incorrect let me know and I'll update.

Comment: I tried both options, for first option i am getting below error: Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //select[@formcontrol="Designation" because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//select[@formcontrol="Designation"' is not a valid XPath expression. For second option i am not getting error, but option from dropdown is not selected. I tried with EmpDesignation.element(by.cssContainingText('option','BodyGuard')).click(); also, but same error as option 1.

Comment: @MM I had a typo in my answer which was missing a square bracket for `EmpDesignation` element. Could you try once again?

Comment: formcontrol also need to be changed to formcontrolname. element(by.xpath("//select[@formcontrolname='Designation']")), it working.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that also

Answer (score 0):

First you need to click on `select` element, and then `option`.

`options` are not visible yet

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const designation = element(by.css('select.form-control>option'));
```

**in your test**

```
 designation.sendKeys('CEO');
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: seems to be not working. Getting error - Failed: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a css selector and use the 'value' attribute:

```
var CEO = element(by.css('[value="CEO"]'));
```

Then the code would look like this:

```
let EmpDesignation = element(by.xpath('//select[@formcontrol="Designation"]'));
return EmpDesignation.click()
   .then(function(){
       return CEO.click();
   });
```